# Create a distribution of immigrants across commune- by country of origin

Tags: aggregate, stata, reshape

I would like to transform the table in Stata that I have on the left to the one on the right. I want to calculate the percentage every immigrant has (by nationality) in every commune.

[image: Here is the outcome I would like to have]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This may work for your example

```
foreach x in 1111 8218 { 
     egen nat`x' = mean(nationality == `x'), by(commune) 
} 

tabdisp commune, c(nat1111 nat8218)
```

That said

```
 tab commune nationality
```

is a simpler start -- and watch out for the options of `tabulate`.

Please note

1. Attempting code is expected here, regardless of whether you are new to any software.
2. Sample data presented as images can help, but sample data presented as code is even better.
3. Your example is ambiguous on whether variables are held as numeric or string, which affects whether code will work.

#2 and #3 are explained in the very detailed Stata tag wiki, which you should read.

Comment: Hey Nick, Thank you very much for your answer it was very helpful!!! I tried to to present the sample data as code but it did not work.